# iOS Safari Browser not responding to HTML5 Video Mute/Unmute

Tags: html, ios, html5-video

On iOS Safari browsers I've observed that on first page load, the video controls respond to mute/unmute regardless of the state of the silent toggle. When you navigate away from the page and later go back to the video, the video controls no longer respond to mute/unmute.

To recreate:

1. On iOS device, open [Html 5 Video Tryit](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)
2. Ensure iPhone silent toggle is ON. (muted)
3. Play video, mute/unmute; Cool it works with the toggle on
4. Click ad at top of page; Just to navigate somewhere else
5. Use back button and attempt step 3; Video is always muted

I've tried debugging through both scenarios and validated video mute state changes were occurring as expected. Appears to be iOS Safari bug, but looking for work around.

Comment: Haven't looked at this yet, but 'when you navigate away and later go back to the video' suggests that the video has downloaded to cache, or the device recognises it and applies incorrect behaviour - as such wondering if preventing the cache from occuring could help, i.e. fake 'First viewed' all the time.

Comment: What device and iOS are you using, I have followed your steps exactly and the video works as expected ( all functionalities work normally )

I am using **Iphone X** - **iOS 13.1.3**

Comment: What access do you have? Serverside? Front end code? iOS App? What is the use case?

Comment: I have access to the entire stack. I cannot go into specifics of use case, but it's close to as simple as the above steps I outlined to recreate. We've observed the issues on a variety of iPhone devices and iOS versions, even the latest.